# problem to print result after ajax success

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, feed

Please help to fix this issue with like counting.
i create a news feed like facebook using php mysql and ajax.

problem is that when i click on like button it prints like count from (this value) and showing to all, let say i have 5 posts and like current value for different posts are 100, 200 , 70 , 80 , 578. when I click on first post ajax  success count 100+1 = 101 for first post and for all other post printting same 101 likes. now if i will go to 2nd post and its like value 200, ajax will show 200+1 =201 like. so after click on 2nd post all 5 posts like will show 201. its creating problem for me.  I understand that after ajax success i mentioned to show the value to div class (.ajax_like_result), thats why its showing in every post, same result until i am not clicking on different post.
how to fix this so that when I click on any post it wil show only its real like value??

I try to change the DIV attribute id , instead of class then it only works for first post. other post totally not working. if i set div atribute to class then like is working but printing incorrectly as i mentioned above.

I have pasted below-  html , php and ajax code .  thanks for your help.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){        
    $('.ajax_like').on('click', function () {
        var post_id = $(this).val(); 
        var page = $(this).attr("data-id"); 
        
        $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url: 'like.php',
           data: {post_id:post_id, page:page},
       dataType: 'json',      
          // cache: false,
           success: function(data){                
                $(".ajax_like_result").html(data);              
                }
        });
    });
});
</script>


html : 
<li class="ajax_like" type="submit"  name="data-id" data-id="<?php echo $page;?>" value="<? echo $post_id;?>">                         
               <div class= "ajax_like_result" ><?php print $likes;?></div>
             
    </li>


like.php code :

<?php //user info start
session_start();
$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost", "u1068033_ab24", "ab@24", "u1068033_ab24");
mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");

$id=$_SESSION['id'];


$get_post_id = $_POST['post_id'];

$page = $_POST['page'];
$sql="SELECT `likes` FROM $page WHERE `post_id`='$get_post_id'";
$query=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
$likes=$row['likes'];
$sql="UPDATE $page SET `likes`=$likes+1 WHERE `post_id`='$get_post_id'";
$query=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$sql="SELECT `likes` FROM $page WHERE `post_id`='$get_post_id'";
$query=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
echo $row['likes'];`enter code here`

?>
```

Comment: Your code is wide open to SQL injection because of POST variables used directly in the SQL - use a [Prepared Statement](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to help mitigate this threat!

Comment: You should indeed rewrite your Php code with prepared queries and select for update to avoid count edits by multiple process.

Answer (score 0):

you are writing the result to all HTML elements with the same class "ajax_like_result" when using this line:
$(".ajax_like_result").html(data);

you can use something such as:

```
$("li[data-id='"+page+"'] div.ajax_like_result").html(data);
```

Also better using native JavaScript and not jQuery, using document.querySelector

```
document.querySelector(`li[data-id='${page}'] div.ajax_like_result`).innerHTML = data;
```

and replace the jQuery AJAX with the native JavaScript [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

example in one piece of code block with native JavaScript (no need for jQuery):

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
  document.querySelectorAll('li[data-id]').forEach((elem)=>{
    elem.addEventListener('click', event => {
      const domElem = event.target;
      const postId = domElem.getAttribute('value');
      const page = domElem.getAttribute('data-id');
      const data = {post_id:postId, page:page};

      console.log({data});

      fetch('like.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
          console.log('Success:', data);
          const selector = `li[data-id='${page}'] div.ajax_like_result`;
          document.querySelector(selector).innerHTML = data;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error('Error:', error);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

and better also to remove from the PHP code the '?>' as the PHP ends the script execution at the end and it will reduce some possible unwanted white spaces.

Comment: thank you very much for your help. your ajax code correction helped me. but javascript not worked. anyway your 1 correction is helped me. so thank your very much for your time and  Best of luck .

Comment: since I do not have your PHP server and didn't check I can understand the problem with the JS code, note that I've wrote links.php instead of like.php (now edit it). check your browser's network tab in the developer tool to see if the data is sent.
In 2022 there is no need using jQuery just to send Ajax, better using the native JavaScript.

Comment: @GalGur-Arie I don’t get why it is better to use JavaScript instead of jQuery if it is loaded.

Comment: @JoelCrypto - Because nowadays native JavaScript has wider support of selectors, better native Ajax using fetch.
The idea is NOT loading the library.
In the past jQuery was good for short selectors, ajax, etc... and supported  several browsers including old IE versions.
Nowadays it is irrelevant as there are web standards which supported by all modern browsers (IE has reach it's end of life by Microsoft earlier this month)

Comment: Actually I still use jQuery because I started JS years ago and I dont really use it now but jQuery is still widely used for easier query selectors and easier syntax in general but I understand your point. It doesn’t mean jQuery should not be used but it should be used wiser.

Comment: @JoelCrypto - I strongly suggesting to reduce its use and move to native JS as the library had security issues and you need to follow and upgrade in order to get those fixes.
all those magics of jQuery with selectors are now available in natvie JS using document.querySelector & document.querySelectorAll.

Answer (score 0):

You should need some corrections on your jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.ajax_like').each( function(){

    $(this).on('click', function () {
    var post_id = $(this).val(); 
    var page = $(this).attr("data-id"); 
    
    $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: 'like.php',
       data: {post_id:post_id, page:page},
   dataType: 'json',      
      // cache: false,
       success: function(data){                
            $(this).find(".ajax_like_result").html(data);              
            }
    });
});
    
})
```

});

Comment: thank you very much for your time and support.  i dont know why it is not working for me. i have copied the code and replaced my present code.